# Can I load a Vagrantfile that loads another Vagrantfile?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm trying to set up an inheritance structure in my forest of Vagrantfiles. Basically I wanted something like this:

```
/base
  Vagrantfile
  /testvm
    Vagrantfile
    /nginx-test
      Vagrantfile
```

The `testvm/Vagrantfile` would load the `base/Vagrantfile` and the `nginx-test/Vagrantfile` would load the `testvm/Vagrantfile`. In my test case, the base `Vagrantfile` specifies one box type (eg `bento/ubuntu-18.04`) and sets 1GB of memory for the VM and some other stuff. The testvm `Vagrantfile` loads that and overrides the box to `bento/ubuntu-22.04` and sets a different hostname. The nginx-test `Vagrantfile` loads that last file and sets its own hostname plus adds another provisioning block to install nginx.

I've tried this but I get this `SystemStackError: stack level too deep` error:

```
$ vagrant up
Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

There was an error loading a Vagrantfile. The file being loaded
and the error message are shown below. This is usually caused by
a syntax error.

Path: /Users/donseiler/vagrant_test/testvm/nginx-test/Vagrantfile
Line number: 5
Message: SystemStackError: stack level too deep
```

I've been searching but haven't found anyone attempting multiple layers of loading yet. I can run `vagrant up` just fine from the `base` and `testvm` directories to bring those machines up. I can't run any vagrant commands from the `nginx-test` directory (not even `vagrant status`, etc)

Here are the file contents:

/base/Vagrantfile:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

NAME = "basevm"
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  # Default to bento bionic box
  config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-18.04"
  config.vm.hostname = NAME

  # Set default virtualbox provider settings
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.name = NAME
    vb.memory = "1024"
    vb.gui = false
  end

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update"
end
```

/base/testvm/Vagrantfile:

```
# Load parent Vagrantfile
load "../Vagrantfile"

# define hostname
NAME = "testvm"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  # Change to jammy
  config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-22.04"

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
    apt-get -y install curl
  SHELL
end
```

/base/testvm/nginx-test/Vagrantfile:

```
# Load parent Vagrantfile
load "../Vagrantfile"

# define hostname
NAME = "nginx-test"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
    apt-get -y install nginx
  SHELL
end
```

UPDATE: It looks like I can do multiple loading just fine as long as I use absolute file paths to the Vagrantfiles (or only use relative paths in the `pwd`'s Vagrantfile, or if all Vagrantfiles are in the same directory). The relative path apparently is relative to the pwd, so when `../Vagrantfile` also tries to load `../Vagrantfile`, it does so from `pwd` and not from the parent dir. Then it becomes somewhat of an infinite loop as the parent dir's Vagrantfile keeps trying to load itself from the child dir until vagrant short-circuits itself.

Basically, it loads Vagrantfiles from wherever but the commands in them are executed from the `pwd`, so relative paths are *always* relative to the `pwd`, NOT relative to where the Vagrantfile lives.

Not being able to use relative paths makes things a little less flexible but at least it's a working alternative.